# Could I set some text to bold in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, text, styles

I have some code like below.

```
  <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>
       {this.props.title}
  </Text>
```

> props.title = Foo loves you

Now, Could I set bold for some text?

For example,

"Foo **loves** you"
or 
"**Foo** loves **you**"

Is it possible?

Like the web,

```
<b>Foo</b> loves <b>you</b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it in react native is as follows;

```
<Text style={styles.text}>
    Foo <Text style={styles.bold}>loves</Text> you.
</Text>
```

which results in Foo **loves** you. In your `styles.bold` just giving `fontWeight: bold` is enough, as rest will be inherited from `styles.text`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But how to use in quotes? 

Example, 
data={[{title: 'Foo <Text style={{fontWeight: \'bold\'}}>Loves</Text>You'}

The result is Foo <Text style={{ ........ You.

Comment: If you have that kind of a need, you can actually just supply the Text component itself. Other than that there isn't a way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I understand so I'm trying to use other expression.